# How to pull hardware and software health monitoring information out of ESXi hosts in to my company's webpage?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, hardware

I know the vSphere Client when connected to a host or vCenter provides the health monitoring parameters of the installed servers. But I want this information on my company's website. So the back office team can view it from anywhere all they need is a url and internet.

Any possible solutions to extract that LIVE health information on website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just configured this the other day to pull that info and send it in an email. You can probably figure out how to dump it to a web page.

I'm not deep in the VMware community so credit for this script goes to whomever created it (William Lam).

http://blog.peacon.co.uk/wiki/Esx-health.pl

Comment: I know William, his website (http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/) is a treasure-trove of fantastically useful scripts of all types.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This blogger isn't loading, check if you provide the correct url

Comment: The link works for me. Try Googling "Esx-health.pl".

Comment: it's not working either. LEt me check with some proxy.

Answer (score 0):

ESXi 5.x hostd management agent has embedded SNMP agent which is disabled by default. Unfortunately, it is not supported with free version of ESXi hypervisor as it has read-only access to the filesystem.

When it is enabled it supports sending traps and polling. You can enable and configure it with **vSphere CLI** and **vicfg-snmp.pl** command (basic configuration from GUI is supported as well).  If you want to get hardware events you need to instruct the SNMP agent to communicate with CIM/IPMI interfaces.

Please check official VMware docu for details about  [SNMP configuration, polling, IPMI/CIM](http://tinyurl.com/n68jnbe) . Additionally, the article [Implementing SNMP on vSphere 5](http://tinyurl.com/73la2wb) was very helpful at the time I was testing these features.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way you'll get this data out of vCenter and manipulate it in such a way that'll be useful to display on a website is to use the published API that VMware provides.

Im not sure if you are a developer but check [this page](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html) out to see what can be accessed.

Hope this helps!